# Why does Catherine reply like this to Clark's question?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, christmas-vacation

In [National Lampoon's Christmas Vacation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lampoon's_Christmas_Vacation), Clark asksCatherine about Eddie.

> Clark: Where's Eddie? He usually eats these goddamn things.
>
> Catherine: Oh, not recently, Clark.  He read that squirrels were high
>   in cholesterol.

How does this answer the question Clark asked her?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Throughout the movie Eddie reinforces his 'simple' country life (his worm farm and his pigs), his disregard for common courtesy (emptying his chemical toilet in the storm drain in the street in front of the Griswold house - while guzzling a beer and wearing underwear and a bathrobe) and his family's economic ruin - living in an RV, no job.  The idea that he swears off eating squirrels because he heard they're high in cholesterol is ironic and hilarious, as nothing about his behavior indicates he is either well-read or health conscious.

Comment: Also, the idea that a character like Eddie would actually eat squirrels in the first place - one would naturally assume that Clark was was making a joke himself by suggesting Eddie actually eats squirrels, but then Catherine takes him literally because, apparently, Clark was serious.